# InDesign remove spacing inside paragraph

Tags: spacing, adobe-indesign, paragraph

I have an paragraph in InDesign CC 2015, in that paragraph there is a space in front of a sentence. The space depend on the size of the font but i want to align all the sentences exactly the same. Is that possible?

This is how it looks now:
[The paragraph with sapcing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igBSn.png)

This is how i want it (without adjusting every sentence individually): 
[The paragraph how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNIpb.png)

Best regards,
Robert

Comment: Are you trying to do this via scripting? If not, you may want to ask on the graphicdesign Stack Exchange: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to another stack

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the font.

you can align each line manually (by writing each line in a different text-box of course) or you can edit the font and change the letter's spacing.